# HTML Image Gallery Float Left Underneath

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create an image gallery, and I have the following styling:

```
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
    <img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

How do I make the fourth image go underneath the first image? Note that I theoretically don't know how long the description (text) will be, so I do not want to hard code a height for the image or div.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-basis: calc(33.333333% - 15px);
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
    <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
    <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
    <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: here it is. You can use flexbox to achieve